# I have a large array stored in an hdf5 file , 101 GB, I am working on a system with 64 GB RAM is there any way I can work with a data array this big?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, hdf5

so far I have tried :

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File(path)
```

But this clogs up all the memory.

Please help.

Comment: Does the act of opening the file 'clog up' your memory, or is it further in your code? like, are you literally doing something akin to `dataset[:]` - i.e. trying to load the entire dataset in at once?

Comment: You can do a "lazy load". example: http://hyperspy.org/hyperspy-doc/current/user_guide/big_data.html

Comment: `h5py.File(path)` should **not** _"clog up memory"._ It creates an object reference to your file. It does not read the entire file into memory. There are 2 ways to read data with the file object: 1) ds_data=f['dataset_name'] and 2) arr_data=f['dataset_name'][:]. The second method creates a numpy array of appropriate type, and requires sufficient memory. The first references the dataset, but does not read the data into memory. It is preferred. You can then use numpy slicing notation to access subsets of the dataset as needed. In addition, HDF5 and h5py use chunking to improve I/O performance.